# How does CPU reads data from memory?How cache Plays important role

Tags: c, memory, memory-management, memory-leaks, memcached

I have written a piece of code where I am allocating memory to variable Bextradata (which is member of structure which is  also allocated using malloc) as

```
 Bextradata = (U8_WMC *) malloc(Size);
 memset(Bextradata, 0,Size);
 memcpy(BextraData,pdata + 18,Size);
```

and later trying to read this variable in some other file that too just once .So how does this variable will read from memory.will it place this variable in a cache or it will read it from main memory.

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Depends on what processor+OS platform you are using. I am working on platform where we dont have cache at all.

Comment: Systems with cache read main memory by cache lines (e.g. 32 or 64 bytes at a time). So even if you don't access your variable, there's always a chance, it's already read by some other code.

Answer (score 4):

Before you understand the working of a CPU, you need to understand few terms. The CPU consists of the ALU (for arithmetic and logic operations), the Control Unit and a bunch of registers. The number of registers in a CPU depends on the architecture and varies. The types of registers present are general purpose registers, special purpose registers instruction pointer and a few others. You can read about them. Now when we generally say 32-bit processor or 64-bit processor we're referring to the size of the registers of the CPU.

Now lets look at the following code:

```
int a = 10;
int b = 20;
a = a + b;
```

When the above program is loaded, it's instructions are stored in the main memory. Every instruction in a program is stored in a location in the main memory. Each location has a specific size to it ( Depends on the architecture again, but let's assume it's one byte). Every location has an address to it. The size of the address of particular location in RAM is equal to the size of the instruction pointer. In 64-bit Systems the size of instruction pointer will be 64 bits. That means it can address upto 2^64-1 locations. And since 1 location is generally 1 byte, therefore the total RAM, in theory for 64 bit systems, could be 16 exabytes. ( for 32 bit systems it is 2^32-1 ~ 4 GB)

Now lets look at the first instruction a = 10. This is a store operation. A computer can do following basic operations - add, multiply, subtract, divide, store, jump, etc. You can read the instruction set of any processor, for more on this. Again the instruction set differs from system to system. Coming back, When the program is loaded to memory the instruction pointer points to the first address or base address. In this case it is a = 10. The contents of this location are brought to one of the general purpose registers of the CPU. From this it is taken to the ALU which understands that this is a store operation (cus additional bits are added which represent it as a store operation). The ALU then stores it into one of the locations in RAM and also in the cache. The decision to store it in the cache depends on the compiler and a concept called hardware prefetching. When the compiler parses through a program it sees the frequently used variables and enables them to be stored in cache. In this case, we can see that variable 'a' will be used again so the compiler adds additional intermediate instructions to the program, to store it in the cache as well. Why? For faster access. (In terms of speed always remember Registers > Cache > RAM > Disc )

After the first instruction is executed, the instruction pointer is incremented and it now points to the second instruction, that is, b = 20. The same happens with this as well.

The third is a = a + b. For this there are actually four operations (if u look at the assembly level), that are, 1) Fetch a , 2) Fetch b , 3) Add a and b, 4) store result in a. Now since the variables a and b are present in cache, they are brought from those locations. They are then added and the result is stored back to a.

I hope you understood how it works.

Also you need to know that when a program is loaded in the main memory, it occupies a certain space. This space is called a segment. It has a base address and a final address. You can assume the base address as the first instruction and final address as the last instruction. If from your program you try to dereference a pointer that points from outside this segment, you get the famous error - Segmentation fault. For example :

```
int *ptr = NULL;
printf(*ptr);
```

This will give me a segmentation fault as I am trying to dereference a pointer that stores an address whose value is NULL and since NULL is not in the segment, it will give a seg fault.

Comment: Now since the variables a and b are present in cache, they are brought from those locations. They are then added and the result is stored back to a.:->Is this result updated in both places?I mean RAM as well as cache

Comment: It depends on a concept called as cache prefetching. When the compiler compiles the code it analyzes the recurrence of a particular variable. If for example after that instruction, i.e., a = a + b , you have one more instruction that uses variable a, then it's logical to store it in the cache as well, right? The compiler would do that for you by adding additional instructions, during compilation. This is called software prefetching.

Comment: While this is sort of correct at the conceptual level, even the simplest optimizing compiler will realize that the code is the same as `int a = 30;` and that it doesn't have to store `b` anywhere. And perhaps not `a` either, depending on what happens next.